# How do I use shuffle on List QueryDocumentSnapshot results and use them in a forEach

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to shuffle these firebase results, how do I use the `.shuffle()` on `List<QueryDocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>` in `Future.forEach(result.docs`. It won't accept `Future.forEach(result.docs.shuffle()` as a parameter

[image]

```
 List<QueryDocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> mixed_results_random = result.docs.shuffle();
 
 Future.forEach(result.docs,  //won't accept mixed_results_random 
        (DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> element) {
      try {
           //do stuff...
```

Comment: `result.docs.shuffle()` is a `void` while `result.docs..shuffle()` is a `List` - see https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List/shuffle.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do this is `result.docs..shuffle()`

```
 Future.forEach(result.docs..shuffle(),  //works
        (DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> element) {
      try {
           //do stuff...
```

**The reason:**

`result.docs.shuffle()` is a void while `result.docs..shuffle()` is a List

api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List/shuffle.html